# How can I add additional facilities in custom scenarios?

Tags: sumo, flow-project

I'm wondering how can I add additional facilities in custom scenarios, like parking area or bus stops? I have finished the corresponding .add.xml file, but don't know how to import it into the custom scenario. Can I use any functions to set up these additional parameters?

[Repost by Chenhui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry point to creating the xml files SUMO uses is located in the file `/path/to/flow/core/kernel/scenario/traci.py`. The easiest way to include a bus stop is to take a look at the `generate_cfg` function, wherein you can add a line such as `# add.append(E('busStop', id='testtest', lane='bottom_0'))`, which will append the instruction to include a bus stop to the .add.xml file. Note that this does require editing a base class, meaning that if you want to switch between multiple scenarios, it will attempt to add a bus stop in each of those scenarios -- there isn't currently a way to include special fixtures from specialized scenarios.